# How solve gensim KeyError when I try to have a document's vector?

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I read the following code to learn a doc2vec model.Each document is defined as a text/line between two lines :

- clueweb09-en0001-XX-XXXXX
- end_clueweb09-en0001-XX-XXXXX

This is my code:

```
 path='/home/work/Step2/test-input/html'


alldocs = []  # will hold all docs in original order


for fname in os.listdir(path):
    with open(path+'/'+fname) as alldata:
        for line in alldata:
            docId= line
            print docId
            context= alldata.next()
            #print context
            tokens = gensim.utils.to_unicode(context).split()
            end=alldata.next()
            alldocs.append(LabeledSentence(tokens[:],[docId]))

model = Doc2Vec(alpha=0.025, min_alpha=0.025)  # use fixed learning rate
model.build_vocab(alldocs)
for epoch in range(10):
    model.train(alldocs)
    model.alpha -= 0.002  # decrease the learning rate
    model.min_alpha = model.alpha  # fix the learning rate, no decay

# store the model to mmap-able files
model.save(path+'/my_html_model.doc2vec')
```

But I got the error when I wrote *model.docvecs['clueweb09-en0001-01-34238']* but when I write *model.docvecs[0]* I got the result.

This is the error I got:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getLearingDoc.py", line 40, in <module>
    print model.docvecs['clueweb09-en0001-01-34238']
  File "/home/flashkar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/doc2vec.py", line 341, in __getitem__
    return self.doctag_syn0[self._int_index(index)]
  File "/home/flashkar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/doc2vec.py", line 315, in _int_index
    return self.max_rawint + 1 + self.doctags[index].offset
KeyError: 'clueweb09-en0001-01-34238'
```

I do not have experiences in python and gensim please tell me how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure a tag of *exactly* `'clueweb09-en0001-01-34238'` – no stray newlines/etc – was presented during training?

You can see all the string doctags that are known to the model in the keys of the `model.docvecs.doctags` dict, or in the list `model.docvecs.offset2doctag`.